# Solving 80-20-20 triangle problem

Tags: geometry, triangles, puzzle

I am trying to understand the solution of 80-20-20 triangle problem as stated here http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/Classical4.shtml#Knop

One thing I cannot get understand from the solution is how BP = CD. Pointers on this is appreciated. The rest of the solution is fine.

Comment: $\triangle BCD$ is isosceles, with base angles $50^\circ$, so that $\overline{BC}\cong\overline{CD}$. And $\triangle BCP$ is constructed to be equilateral, so that $\overline{BP}\cong\overline{BC}$.

Comment: My answer is like Blue's...so I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\angle CBD = 50$ degrees and $\angle ACB = 80$ degrees, so that gives you $\angle BDC=50$ degrees.From this, you know that $\triangle BCD$ is isosceles, so $BC=CD$ and hence $BP=CD$. Then, $P$ is constructed as the third vertex of an equilateral triangle with base $BC$, so $BP=BC$ and so $BP=BC=BD$.